# VTK: update data points in renderWindow at every simulation timestep

Tags: c++, vtk

There is a simulation application which outputs some vtk point data every timestep and I would like to render this data at every timestep and also keep it interactive.

I have created a pipeline which takes simulation points (`points->SetInputData(data)`) as an input and applies a set of filters to it. For the sake of testing I've created a simple timer and added an observer reacting on the timer event:

```
  renderWindowInteractor->AddObserver(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, cb);
  int timerId = renderWindowInteractor->CreateRepeatingTimer(1000);
```

This works just as I want it. The only problem left is to add a custom user event. Basically I want to trigger some event at the end of each simulation timestep and update the model in the render window. I saw some of the VTK examples but I still don't get how to do this for my case. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the visualization pipeline using SetInputConnection connected to the filter, then all you have to do is call Render() on the render window periodically.

Comment: what about with `setinputdata` method

Comment: It could be made to work; depending on what exactly the updates are you may need to call `poly->Modified()` on every update so that the filters/mappers get updated.